# Magento multi-domain with seperate backend domain

Tags: magento

Would is be possible to have Magento to be installed on domain-a.com but not using this domain as store front?

like this:

- domain-a.com magento installation and backend access
- domain-b.com store front 1
- domain-c.com store front 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to restrict the acccess to that domain only on your admin folder in your `.htaccess` or your vhost.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-multi-site-multi-domain-setup

here is a good tutorial.